# How to embedd Vimeo password protected videos in app using ionic 3 framework

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, vimeo

I am trying to embed Vimeo password protected videos on Ionic3 App, I am getting output as specified in the screen, in one video i am not getting any option to add password, in the other screen I am getting the option to enter password, but screen gets refreshed each time I enter the password. I am tried searching these issue but found nothing, Can any one please help as I am new to frontend [attached Screen for videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EYqF.png)
posted the same issue on vimeo player github issues page as well: [vimeo player github issues](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/144)